# Google PageSpeed Insights error: client could not parse server reply

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Our website returns "Lighthouse returned error: RPC::SERVER_ERROR: Client could not parse server reply; initialization error is: Dismiss" on Google Pagespeed Insights after around 60% is complete, on every page under the website. How can we get more details related to this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like PageSpeed Insights is timing out.
Check chrome developer tools to see your page load speed.
Check your time to first bite (TTFB) to help determine where the slowness is occurring, server side or client side.